How to render data of a dictionary when the keys are not known?
Backend returns a list of dictionaries that the name of keys are different based on the request. For example, imagine the following data is returned.
users = [
  {
    'name':'John',
    'age':'20'
  },
  {
    'name':'Jane',
    'age':'22'
  }
]

If I know data related to "name" and "age" are returned, I can render them as the following:
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
   <tr>
     <td>{{user.name}}</td>
     <td>{{user.age}}</td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>

But in my case, I don't have the name of keys. So how can I render them in .html?
P.s.
I can get the list of keys as following:
for (let key in this.users[0]) {
   this.columns.push(key);
}

This way I know the keys are "name" and "age" but I don't know how to use them in .html.

It seems like this question should be tagged with angular or whatever front-end technology you're using in the question. Right now as a pure TypeScript question I'd say just... index into the value with the key, like for (let k in obj) { console.log(k, obj[k]) }. But we'd need a [mre] to be sure. Please [edit] to tag and provide a reproducible example.

You can use the KeyValuePipe.
@for (entry of user | keyvalue; track entry.key) {
  <td>{{entry.value}}</td>
}


Note that this is the newer control flow syntax: https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow

Thanks  @Unmitigated, using your code I get: key: 0 value: [object Object] key: 1 value: [object Object]. I think it is because I have a list of dictionaries!

@user6781 You were supposed to place this code inside <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users"><tr>{LOOP HERE!}</tr></ng-container>, note that it is iterating over user (the current object), not users.

you are right, now it works as expected, thank you.

@user6781 Happy to help.
